# switchMapSingle() doesn't cancel previous request

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-room, rx-java3

I have DB table 'order' with 6000 rows and I want to create searching in it by number using switchmap for canceling previous request. But it's not work, it always returns result of previous request. What is wrong with my code?

**Example:** enter 1..0..7 returns 107%, then 10%, then 1%. It should return only 107%

```
disposable.add(
                Observable.just(orderParameter)
                .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .switchMapSingle(orderParameter1 -> orderInteractor.getSearchOrderList(orderParameter1))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(orders -> {
                    getView().showOrders(orders);
                }, throwable -> Timber.e(throwable.getMessage())));


@Query("SELECT `order`.order_id as id, " +
            "client.last_name || ' ' || SUBSTR(client.first_name,1,1) || '. ' || SUBSTR(client.middle_name,1,1) || '.' as client_name, " +
            "`order`.status as status, " +
            "agency.short_name as agency_name, " +
            "`order`.creation_date as date, " +
            "`order`.price as price " +
            "FROM `order`, agency, client where " +
            "`order`.status =:status and agency.id = `order`.agency_id and client.id = `order`.client_id " +
            "and `order`.agency_id =:agencyId and `order`.order_id like :orderId")
    Single<List<Order>> getOrdersByStatusAndOrderIdAndAgencyId(String status, String orderId, long agencyId);


public class OrderParameter {
    public long searchNumber = -1;
    public long agencyId = -1;
}


OrderParameter orderParameter = new OrderParameter();
        try {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(searchText.trim())) {
                orderParameter.searchNumber = -1;
            } else {
                orderParameter.searchNumber = Long.parseLong(searchText);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        orderParameter.agencyId = agencyId;
```

**UPD:** Added getting an OrderParameter

Comment: and how many times you are calling `Observable.just(orderParameter)` ?

Comment: Your setup makes little sense. You'd need a flow that is fed multiple values for `switchMapSingle` to cancel a previous run. It appears you keep creating a fresh flow with one element to run, independent of previous runs.

Comment: @Selvin in example - three times

Comment: @akarnokd May be... Could you show me how to setup this right? Or give a link for detail information about it?

Comment: How do you get that `orderParameter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of RxBinding, try this in onCreate:

```java
disposable.add(
    RxView.clicks(textField).map(v -> {
            String searchText = searchTextField.getText().toString();
            OrderParameter orderParameter = new OrderParameter();
            try {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(searchText.trim())) {
                    orderParameter.searchNumber = -1;
                } else {
                    orderParameter.searchNumber = Long.parseLong(searchText);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            orderParameter.agencyId = agencyId;
            return orderParameter;
          })
          .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .distinctUntilChanged()
          .switchMapSingle(orderParameter1 -> 
                  orderInteractor.getSearchOrderList(orderParameter1))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(orders -> {
               getView().showOrders(orders);
          }, throwable -> Timber.e(throwable.getMessage())));
```

Comment: Thank you) I have tried RxSearchView and it works without using switchMap.